# How to interrupt echo command executed within python process

Tags: python, shell

Earlier i used file.write() in python to write data to the file. But on os reboot, as open(file,'w') truncates the file contents, i'm getting an empty file. Instead can i use echo command using subprocess.call() to write contents into the file? Will echo command also opens the destination file by truncating contents or is there any other way to check what echo command actually does by interrupting the process.

I've already tried executing echo command in python with a sleep time and killed the python process but i can't actually say if i've properly killed the process at the right time when echo actually writes.

```py
import time
from subprocess import call

#file.txt content: Before change

time.sleep(10)
call('echo "Hello world" > file.txt',shell=True)
print 'done'
```

When i tried to kill the process after 10s, sometimes the o/p of the file will be "Before change" and some may have "Hello world". Is there any possible way to identify this?

Comment: "open(file,'w') truncates the file contents, i'm getting an empty file." Opening a file in write (w) mode empties it before writing, you need to open it in append mode (a) to write more data into it.

Comment: also `echo "Hello world" > file.txt` will also empty `file.txt` before writing anything into it, you need to use `>>` in order to append data to it.

Comment: I don't want to append content. Even i use open(file,'a') and then use seek(0) to move cursor to the starting and tried writing using file.write() i actually got an empty file on os reboot.

Comment: It means i actually tried to kill the process when file.write() tries to append content. Sometimes i killed before it wrote i got the old content.

Comment: Were you perhaps forgetting to close the file after writing to it?  That could certainly leave the file in a state where previous contents were gone, but the new contents hadn't actually been written to disk.

Comment: calling echo to create a file is not necessary.

either you open the file, write the contents and close it, (it will be as good as echo)

or if you want to keep the file open you write to it but you call `fileobj.flush()` after writing.

Comment: @jasonharper, I've used `with open(file,'w')` so it'll automatically close the file, but before it does when the process gets killed, then it'll end up with an empty file.